# How to group cart by vendors and calculate delivery by vendor's in woocommerce using Dokan

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Is there a way to group the products in the WooCommerce cart by vendor and calculate shipping costs for each vendor using Dokan? I want to display the shipping costs for each vendor separately on the checkout page.

To group products from vendors on the cart page